# Significance of challenges cited, in creating anomaly scores out of path length, in original paper for Isolation Forest

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, anomaly-detection, isolation-forest

In the [original paper on Isolation Forest by *Liu*, *Ting* and *Zhou*](https://cs.nju.edu.cn/zhouzh/zhouzh.files/publication/icdm08b.pdf), the authors cite some problems in creating anomaly scores out of the path length $h(x)$ of a point $x$ in an iTree. The text reads as follows (section 2, following definition of "**Path Length**") -

> The difficulty in deriving such a score from $h(x)$ is that while the
> maximum possible height of iTree grows in the order of $n$, the
> average height grows in the order of $log(n)$. Normalization of $h(x)$
> by any of the above terms is either not bounded or cannot be directly
> compared.

I understand the logic about the growth order of maximum possible height and average height for an iTree. I do not understand how

1. use of them to normalize leads to unboundedness of anomaly scores.
2. And then, what type comparison is being referred to, that becomes difficult.

Can these points please be clarified? Please feel free to use mathematical formulations to drive the point. In fact, it is preferred if someone starts with the formulation for the anticipated normalization step itself (just so there is no ambiguity).